# XMPP to show presence and without login in a web application?

Tags: session, xmpp, user-presence

The main problem is, how would you ensure people can login to the xmpp server securely without having to login again from the web app login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to send a `<presence/>` stanza indicating that the user is available. In that case, you need to instantiate a new session, either by logging in manually, or other means.

If you want to automatically login a user and start up the application, try using localStorage, then triggering login so that it seems like the user did not login.

If you wanted to send a `<presence><show>chat</show></presence>` or something akin to that, you might be able to get away with using a preexisting BOSH connection. The problem with that is you won't presence from JIDs in the roster because no probes were sent out.

I recommend the first solution. The second is there more for informational purposes than anything else. And if push comes to shove, go to http://xmpp.org. Look through BOSH XEP (if you are using it), RFC 3920 (XMPP Core) and RFC 3921 (XMPP IM).

Comment: How secure can localStorage be? And isn't its support not very good?

Comment: Here's some info about localStorage security: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox3.1/localStorage_Security_Review. Same origin rules apply here, so the only problem is someone else using the same computer. And that's the user's fault. As for the support: Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, IE8+, Chrome 4+ all support it. So it's not too bad.